Do firebase's google Web client ID shouldn't be hardcoded in android app's source code?
I have implemented firebase sign in with google in my android app and initialize sign in options using the below code snippets
// Initialize sign in options the client-id is copied form google-services.json file
GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken("client_id_token")
        .requestEmail()
        .build();

Now when I decompile the app's release build using minifyEnabled true I can find the exact client_id_token in my decompiled activity. Now my question is that whether or not client_id_token is a sensitive information that shouldn't be hardcoded in the source code and if it's a sensitive information then how I can avoid hardcoding it in the app's source code? I have already used minifyEnabled true .
I have done some internet searching and all that I have understood that client id is not a sensitive info but client secret is. But still I am confused. Thanks.

Firebase configs are designed to be stored n the client and are basically public information after you publish your app.
